# Setting up https on a single instance running Docker

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to make connections to my Elastic Beanstalk instance https. I have followed the docs but still am only connecting through http(only http requests work, where https requests say refuse). In my code (which is dart) I am serving on port 8080. When I changed it to 80 I got Bad Gateway error. Here is the files in my .ebextensions folder:

```
  Resources:
   sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

n

```
Parameters:
  privatekey:
    Type: String
    Description: "The path to the private key in Amazon S3"
    Default: "https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/server.key"
  publiccert:
    Type: String
    Description: "The public certificate"
    Default: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----


##############################################
#### Do not modify values below this line ####
##############################################

files:
  # nginx HTTPS configuration
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # HTTPS Server

      server {
        listen 443;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://docker;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;

          proxy_set_header Connection "";
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
      }

  # Public certificate
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: { "Ref": "publiccert"}

  # Private key
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: { "Ref" : "privatekey" }

container_commands:
  01restart_nginx:
    command: "service nginx restart"

Resources:
  # Use instance profile to authenticate to S3 bucket that contains the private key
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          roleName:
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
```

n

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
          default        "upgrade";
          ""            "";
      }

      server {
          listen 8080;

          gzip on;
          gzip_comp_level 4;
          gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

          if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
              set $year $1;
              set $month $2;
              set $day $3;
              set $hour $4;
          }
          access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

          access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

          location / {
              set $redirect 0;
              if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                set $redirect 1;
              }
              if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
                set $redirect 0;
              }
              if ($redirect = 1) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
              }

              proxy_pass            http://docker;
              proxy_http_version    1.1;

              proxy_set_header    Connection            $connection_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header    Upgrade                $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
              proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details. You haven't even provided EB platform version that you are using.

Comment: TBH I have no idea what version of EB means. I have Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.9.